# Binding kendo ui grid columns headers to a json file

Tags: json, kendo-ui, grid

I'm using a kendo ui grid, and I want to bind the columns headers to a json file, instead of specifying it directly in the controller.

Is there a way to bind it as in the dataSource?

If not, then how?

This is what I tried, but it does not work:

```
$scope.options = {
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: "myData.json"
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                schema  : {
                    data: "mySchema"
                }
            },
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            resizable: true,
            columns:{
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: "app/data/headers.json"
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of headers.json?

Comment: Sure, thank you:
[{
    "field": "field1",
    "title": "field1"
},
{
    "field": "field2",
    "title": "field2"
},
{
    "field": "field3",
    "title": "field3"
},
....
....

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a function to get the headers as follows :

```
  function returnColumns(){
    var retVal;
    $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          url: "app/data/headers.json",
          data: data,
          success: success,
          async: false,
      success: function(data){
        retVal = $.parseJson(data);
      }
    });


    return retVal;
  }
```

Then, in your assignment of columns, you can simply do the following :

```
columns : returnColumns(),
```

We can test this further, if you provide the format of the json file you are loading.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi srinivas, thank you for answering. I'm using angular, so I tried what you suggested (calling a function) with angular's $http service. Problem is, that it is asynch, and the columns headers are not populated... the $http call is returning with the correct data (I checked on debug), but I suspect that it happens when the grid is already built, and therefore not updated with the returned data.

Comment: I have made async : false in the .ajax call. Did you try jquery or are you constrained to use angular. I don't have much experience in Angular, but it should have a similar way to force async to be false I guess.

Comment: Your answer pointed me to a new direction. I tried to run the $http in the separate function and populate an array in the scope, which is binded to the columns. The binding is broken but now it is an angular issue, so I will post a new question about it. Thank you very much for your help!